# R's nnet needs decay to perform with sin() like function, why variant reproducibility

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I've noticed that for `sin()` like data, I need to use `decay` which is available in `nnet` to get the ANN to perform. Why would that be in theory?   Also when I run `runNN(0.02)` over and over, sometimes the model performs beautifully (relative rmse of 0.04) and other times poorly (relative rmse of 0.42). How can one make the training of the `nnet` not so dependent on the random initialization of the weights?

```
while(runNN(0.02)>0.1){} # This works but it seems sloppy.
```

Is there a way to set the training parameters better in order to always converge on the "best" result?

*For the training data: Imagine a restaurant has the most customers at noon and the qty of the tips is highest at noon and we want to make a neural net predict tips gained in an hour.*

```
library(quantmod)
library(nnet)
print("start")
runNN = function(decayParam) {  
  data = data.frame(h=1:24); 
  data$qty <- sin(data$h/48*2*pi)*1000
  data$v = c(paste("actual",decayParam))
      mynn <- nnet(qty~h,data,size=2,decay = decayParam,linout = TRUE,maxit=2000) 
      pred = data.frame(h=1:24); 
      ps <- predict(mynn,pred);
      pred$qty = ps[,1];
  pred$v = c(paste("pred",decayParam))
      rsd = sqrt(mean((data$qty-pred$qty)^2))/mean(data$qty)
  rsds = paste("rsd=",rsd)
  print(rsds)  
  alldata <- rbind(data,pred)
  print(ggplot(data=alldata, aes(x=h, y=qty, group=v, color=v)) + 
          geom_line() + 
          geom_point()+theme_classic()+ggtitle(rsds));
  return(rsd)
}
print(runNN(0))    # with no decay
print(runNN(0.02)) # with decay

runNN(0)     # with no decay - tends to converge to the population mean
runNN(0.02)  # with decay - works better, but if you run this multiple times, 
             #  sometimes it converges badly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is having a while loop repeatably create NNs of a small size looking for the best root mean square error.

Essentially:
For hidden layer size of 1 to 10 do
For trials of 1 to 10:
Create NN and test for rmse with test data.
Remember NN and best rmse for particular hidden layer size.

Review results choosing the smallest hidden layer size which had a small rmse.

By separating the data into test and train sets, this way you don't pick an over fit NN.

Comment: The real issue is that a learning rate of 0.02 is far too large!